# SqlPubWiz Command Line: Error: Operation is not valid du e to the current state of the object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to script a db from the command line as part of a powershell script. If i run the gui it works.. if I run the same type of operation from the command line it fails:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4\SqlPubWiz" script -d DBNAME DBNAME.sql -schemaonly -targetserver 2008

for some reason I'm getting the following output and I have no idea how to fix!

`Generating script for database DBNAME
- Generating only metadata script
- Generating script targeted for SQL Server 2008
Gathering list of objects to script
Scripting objects
................................................Error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard
Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's what I had: it appears that DBNAME is case sensitive.

Found on:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/ecfd4379-ee88-4a60-81a4-d6cc9542b1ff

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I Had the same error. Fixing the name of the database worked. Thanks